# Jquery Sortable, reorder list then write to mySQL database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Im trying to write a list, which allows user to reorder it and save the reordered list to mySQL.

Jquery:

```
 <script>
     $(function() {
         $('#sortable').sortable({
          axis: 'y',
          update: function (event, ui) {
           var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            $.ajax({
              data: data,
              type: 'POST',
              //url: 'index.php' sending data to the same page
            });
           }
        });
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
     });
    </script>
```

PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $value) {
// Execute statement:
// UPDATE [Table] SET [Position] = $i WHERE [EntityId] = $value
//$i++;
}
?>
```

The errors I get from PHP_error_reporting: undefined index: data, Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Please provide us with full code in the Index.php page where are you getting the `$task` from or how did you declared it, the warning is basicly telling you that the `$task` is not something which you can use inside a `foreach()` loop

Comment: Try to add `var_dump($_POST);` before loop and look what you received

Comment: @Slava Rozhnev  I get array(0){}. PHP didn't receive the object from ajax POST somehow. I inspected the network activity on the console it says object array successfully sent by ajax.  
Headers tab: POST status 200
Request: item[]: [0=>"2", 1=>"1"] Thats the value I'm expecting when using POST PHP but the array doesn't show up in PHP when I use $_POST['data'] var_dump($_POST), print_r($_POST). None of them mentioned is working

Answer (score 0):

Try `$data = $_POST['data'] or $_REQUEST['data']`

You can decode the $data using json_decode() and access your attributes.

like `json_decode($data);`

Comment: That's where the problem appears. Error reporting keeps saying undefined variable I've been trying with both $_REQUEST $_POST if(isset( $_REQUEST[] / $_POST[] ) ). None of them is doing what it should.

Comment: So first, you have to fix the way you send data. Make sure your page receive the POST request, then try your own logic. You should really define 'url:', sending data to the same page is not a relevant excuse in that case.